# A function whose first and second derivatives have zero expectation but not the third derivative

Tags: probability, probability-theory, functions, random-variables

I came across this interesting problem through a friend and I am trying to find a solution to it. Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be the standard Gaussian random variable. The goal is to find a function (can assume all nice properties ) $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$
E[f'(X)]=0, E[f''(X)]=0, \text{ and } E[f'''(X)] \neq 0 .
$$

Does there exist any such $f$ satisfying the above properties? It's not sure if it's true or not. I feel this problem is closely related to Hermite polynomials but not sure. Can anyone suggest a method to solve this?

The approach that I am currently using is through Taylor expansion. Suppose $f(x)=\sum_{i} \alpha_i x^i$. Then the above conditions imply that
$$
\sum_k \alpha_{2k+1} \cdot (2k+1)!!=0, \\
\sum_k \alpha_{2k+2} \cdot (2k+2) \cdot (2k+1)!!=0,\\
\sum_k \alpha_{2k+3} \cdot (2k+3) \cdot (2k+2) \cdot (2k+1)!! \neq 0,
$$
where $!!$ is the double factorial. This doesn't shed much light on how the coeffecients $\alpha_i$ should be.

Comment: Maybe try to play with [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) (this seems relevant)?

Comment: @ClementC.: I just found the answer. Take $f=x^3-3x$.

Answer (score 4):

An $L^2$ function $f(x)$ has Hermite expansion
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n H_n(x)
$$
where the coefficient is given by
$$
d_n = \frac{1}{n!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)H_n(x)\omega(x)dx
$$
where $\omega(x)$ is the Gaussian weighting function
$$
\omega(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}.
$$
Equivalently, by integrating by parts, the coefficient is equal to the expectation of the $n^{th}$ derivative
$$
d_n= \frac{1}{n!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial^n f(x)}{\partial x^n}\omega(x)dx\\
= \frac{1}{n!}\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial^n f(x)}{\partial x^n}\right]
$$

So, to expand upon the answer from @pikachuchameleon, any function whose Hermite expansion starts at $n=3$ will have your desired property.

If you are interested, here is a preprint with more properties of Hermite expansion:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/352374514_A_GENERAL_EXPRESSION_FOR_HERMITE_EXPANSIONS_WITH_APPLICATIONS